# Getting value of a char* exported by unmanaged dll in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

Im trying to get a value of a string exported by an unmanaged dll.

The string in the dll is declared as

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) const char* _Version = "0.1";
```

The code I'm using to get the value is below. I get the address for the variable from the call to `GetProcAddress` but `Marshal.PtrToStringAuto` returns garbage...

Whats wrong?

```
    public string GetDllVersion()
    {
            IntPtr lib = LoadLibrary(@"some.dll");
            if(lib == IntPtr.Zero)
                    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

            IntPtr procAddress = GetProcAddress(lib, "_Version");
            var ver2 = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(procAddress);

            if(!FreeLibrary(lib))
                    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            return ver2;
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

    [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed this by dereferencing the pointer from GetProcAddress:

```
procAddress = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(GetProcAddress(lib, "_Version"));
```

Also changed the way to read the string per suggestion from Hans Passant (other answer):

```
var ver2 = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(procAddress);
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi() here.

"Auto" means "operating system default".  With Windows 98 and ME on the endangered species list, that's very likely Unicode on your machine.  Your string isn't const wchar_t*.

Comment: I think it's a bit more complicated. The address returned in IntPtr procAddress is a pointer, so I have to dereferense it to get to the value. So, for example, on my last run I got 0x092c7000 in procAddress which pointed to 0x092c553c which in turn held the value... Anyway, just changing to PtrToStringAnsi didn't help.

Comment: Can't argue that.  Exporting data from a DLL is *very* uncommon, not exactly sure what the rules are.  Use Marshal.ReadIntPtr().

Comment: +1 "Exporting data from a DLL is very uncommon." I guess you've never had the joy of coding against the Python C API! ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution; checked-it, it works.

```
IntPtr procAddress = GetProcAddress(lib, "_Version");
IntPtr verAddress = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(procAddress);
var ver2 = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(verAddress);
```

Comment: Already got it, see my own answer. Upvoted for the effort though. =)